# Formatting a string in Python is giving me a file not found error

Tags: python, string, pandas, format, ioerror

I am new to python and trying to work with Pandas to do some work with several .csv files that have predictable names, Log_(yyyy/mm/dd).

What I'm planning is simple enough, but opening the file is giving me problems.

```
today = date.today()
m,d,y = today.month, today.day, today.year

file_name = 'Log_{}-{}-{}'.format(y,m,d)
pd.read_csv(file_name)
```

This will give me an error, but this works

```
file_name = 'Log_2015-01-10'
pd.read_csv(file_name)
```

They print the same thing, and `str(file_name)` doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: `m,d,y = today.month, today.year, today.day` this is wrong, it should be `m,y,d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems: your tuple assignment swaps the day and year values, and you need to zero-pad  values below 10. You are actually producing the string `'Log_10-1-2015'`, not `'Log_2014-01-10'`.

Formatting a date into a string is easiest done by leaving formatting to the date object rather than extracting the individual components yourself:

```
today = date.today()
file_name = 'Log_{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(today)
```

The `%` fields are [`strftime()` formatting instructions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) that use zero-padding by default.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> today = date.today()
>>> 'Log_{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(today)
'Log_2015-01-11'
```

Yes, it is already the 11th in my timezone. :-)

Comment: Weird, I that first mistake was a typo when I was posting this, I switched the format to what you wrote and it worked fine, thanks.